# Вылетает приложение при вызове popBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragment

Вылетает данная ошибка `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`, когда хочу выполнить `mManager.popBackStack()`. Загвоздка в том, что обычно выполняется нормально, но эта ошибка выскакивает, если на активити я добавил два фрагмента, затем перешел на другую активити и с нее обратно на первую. И после этих манипуляций вылетает эта ошибка. Читал, что после onResume нельзя вызывать для менеджера фрагментов .commit(), но в popBackStack он и не вызывается.

UPD:

Решение оказалось простым: надо было создавать фрагмент в активити, а не внутри другого фрагмента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в том, что метод `popBackStack()` внутри себя вызывает метод `checkStateLoss()`, который и выкидывает `Exception`, который вы поймали.

Comment: Есть какое нибудь решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Насколько я могу судить из source code FragmentManager, нет. Посмотрите внимательней на свой код скорее всего там есть логическая ошибка.

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что я фрагмент пихал внутрь другого фрагмента. Сделал, чтобы он добавлялся в активити и проблема исчезла

Comment: Для работы с фрагментами внутри фрагментов используйте getChildFragmentManager()